# C# Split File Name Beginner Exercise

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a directory filled with multiple excel files that I would like to rename. The names all have leading integers and a '`-`'. For example: **`0123456-Test_01`**. I would like to rename all of the files within this directory by removing this prefix. **`0123456-Test_01`** should just be **`Test_01`**. I can rename a hard coded instance of a string, but am having trouble getting the files and renaming all of them.

My code is below. Any help is appreciated, as I am clearly new to C#.

```
public static void Main()
{
    //Successfully splits hardcoded string
    var temp = "0005689-Test_01".Split('-');
    Console.WriteLine(temp[1]);
    Console.ReadLine();

    //Unsuccessful renaming of all files within directory
    List<string> files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\acars\Desktop\B", "*").ToList();
    System.IO.File.Move(@"C:\Users\acars\Desktop\B\", @"C:\Users\acars\Desktop\B\".Split('-'));

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        var temp = files.Split('-');
        return temp[1];
    };            
}
```

Comment: `return temp[1];` will exit your program (or throw an exception if there was not a `-` in the filename).  Where is the code to rename the file?

Comment: do you have to use C# or could it even be powershell? for simple renaming i would recommend powershell.

Comment: Apart from the right comment made by @Tim, are you sure that, after removing the integer part, you don't end up with files having the same name?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I added some code above that would hopefully execute the actual renaming

Comment: @AndrewC10 - Your addition won't do what you think it will, because the second argument will be an array, not a filepath.   What you need to do is get the list of files in the directory, loop through them and split, take the second element of the split, and then rename the file.  `Move` won't rename it, it will *move* it.

Answer (score 3):

There are some errors to fix in your code.

The first one is the wrong usage of the variable `files`. This is the full list of files, not the single file that you want to split and move. As explained comments you should use the iterator result stored in the variable *file*

The most important problem is the fact that the [File.Move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx) method throws an exception if the destination file exists. After removing the first part of your filename string, you cannot be sure that the resulting name is unique in your directory.
So a check for the existance of the file before the Move is mandatory.

Finally, it is better use [Directory.EnumerateFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx) because this method allows you to start the execution of your moving code without loading first all filenames in memory in a list. (In a folder full of files this could make a noticeable difference in speed)

```
public static void Main()
{
     string workPath = @"C:\Users\acars\Desktop\B";
     foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(workPath)
     {
         string[] temp = file.Split('-');
         if(temp.Length > 1)
         {
             string newName = Path.Combine(workPath, temp[1]);
             if(!File.Exists(newName))
                File.Move(file, newName);
         }
     }
 }
```

Pay also attention to the comment below from CodeNotFound. You are using an hard-coded path so the problem actually doesn't exist, but if the directory contains a single `"-"` in its name then you should use something like this to get the last element in the splitted array

```
 string newName = Path.Combine(workPath, temp[temp.Length-1]);
```

Comment: Of course, assuming path doesn't contain `-` like `C:\Users\acars\Desk-top\B`

Comment: You should replace `file.Split('-')` with `Path.GetFileName(file).Split('-')` to aboid the case where the directory name already contains '-'

Comment: @CodeNotFound You are correct of course, but given the fact that this is an exercise and the directory seems to be hard-coded, perhaps your comment is enough to warn the OP of this problem. Just to not complicate the answer at this stage.

Comment: Oh, well, I can't leave the answer without fixing the problem you have outlined.